# How to make a button "active" on hover when appearing from behind another image?

Tags: css

I hope the title is clear enough. I have an image and a div in the same place in a grid. The div (which is behind the image) has a button. When I use :hover { opacity: 0%; } on the image and the div comes to the front, im not able to click on the button. How can i solve this problem?
[html + scss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXllb.png)

Comment: Code should be text, not Image. Please read [ask] and create a **textual** [mcve]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [ask]. Especially the part that says "DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages,etc."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use opacity for your image, because because your image would still be on top, only with no opacity.

Try something with `z-index`.

```css
.card {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.card > div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.card img {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  visibility: visible;
  max-width: 200px;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 100%;
  /*transform: visibility .3s ease;*/
  transition: opacity .5s ease, z-index 0s 0s;
}

.card:hover img {
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .75s ease, z-index 0s .75s;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="">
  <div>
    <button>
      click
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Makes sense with the opacity. But the button has to appear smoothly through transition. So i guess I somehow need the opacity.

Comment: @Jasper, I updated the code and combined ```z-index``` and ```opacity```.

Comment: Thank you very much. But somehow, in my code it has not the same result as in yours. I'm just learning and this this is a pretty tough excercise in my opinion! Could you take a quick look at my css whats going wrong?

Comment: Update/add your code, and post in your question.

Comment: Thanks. Not sure where to put it in my question as im new so ill post it here:

<div class="portfolio__1">
            <img src="images/head2.png" class="portfolio__1--img" />
            <div class="portfolio__2">
                <button class="portfolio__2--btn"><strong>Read More</strong></button>
            </div>
        </div>

Ok, this makes it difficult to read..

Comment: https://github.com/Code-Jap/advanced_css